# How can I find out the exact time if the access to the network is not permanent?

Tags: java, android

It takes UTC + 0 for the application to work, but the exact minutes and seconds are needed.

Since access to the network is not permanent, The exact time can not always be determined. If the method is still like that, determine the exact time.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "exact"? I mean... You could buy an atomic clock; but I guess that isn't quite what you had in mind.

Comment: network time.....

Answer (score 2):

If your application is dependent on the network time, what you can do is the following.

When network becomes available:

1. use the network to get the time
2. get system time
3. calculate the difference
4. store the difference
5. use the network time

When network is not available:

1. get the stored difference
2. get system time
3. calculate the needed time
4. use the calculated time

Comment: but if the user changes the time several times outside the network.

Comment: there is no absolute way to ensure that the time you are reading from the device is in any way the real time. even getting time through the network is not 100% reliable. An attacker may still perform a network attack and spoof your time query through the network. You could use your own time server and sign the response, but even then there may be ways around it. As for the reliability of the time of the device, unless you can lock the changes to time on the device, you cannot rely on the device time

Answer (score 0):

use **System.currentTimeMillis()** to get current timestamp and then convert it to minutes with following method

```
    public long getCurrentMinOfHour()
    {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

        return (long)((c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 60 * 1000)) ;
    }
```

Comment: this time is set on the phone and you need to calculate the exact time. The phone may have a modified time